# How to use String Value from sheet as a variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a minor addition to some code where I just want to use a value on the sheet to give me alternate information.

Example:

```
    Dim WHN, Wn18, Wn06, Wn77, Wn26 As String
    Wn18 = "Name1"
    Wn06 = "Name2"
    Wn77 = "Name3"
    Wn26 = "Name4"

    WHN = Range("G2")

    MsgBox WHN
```

Where `Range("G2")` will have a value of one of the four values of Wn18, Wn06, Wn77, or Wn26. I would like the MsgBox in this example to give me the name associated with that value.

So, if `Range("G2").Value` is `Wn06`, I would like the MsgBox to display `Name2`.

I know it is possible to do this with `If` statements, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Also, your declaration block is likely not working the way you think it is. You have declared `Win26` as string. The rest of the variables are unnasigned and thus assumed to be `Variant`. You need to have `Dim WHN as String, Wn18 as String, .......` i.e. each variable must be explicitly assigned

Comment: Maybe two arrays and Application.Match to pull the correct index.

Comment: As @JvdV says, arrays are your friend here, with match, something like so.  Declaring the arrays before hand i'd recommend  `array("Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4")(application.match("cd",array("wn","ab","cd","ef"),0)-1)` will return "Name3"  Also, `choose` may may things more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something similar using a collection

```
Dim WHN As String
Dim Wn_Coll As New Collection

Wn_Coll.Add "Name1", "Wn18"
Wn_Coll.Add "Name2", "Wn6"
Wn_Coll.Add "Name3", "Wn77"
Wn_Coll.Add "Name4", "Wn26"

WHN = Wn_Coll(Range("G2"))

MsgBox WHN
```

Comment: Fantastic! This does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!